# Rails - Create new category (Couldn't find category with ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app where I know

```
def new 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { new_or_edit }
      format.js { 
        @category = Category.new
      }
    end  
end
```

is being called when I click a link.

This leads to new_or_edit being called (defined in the same file).

```
  def new_or_edit
    @categories = Category.find(:all)
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.attributes = params[:category]
    if request.post?
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { save_category }
        format.js do 
          @category.save
          @article = Article.new
          @article.categories << @category
          return render(:partial => 'admin/content/categories')
        end
      end
      return
    end
    render 'new'
  end
```

After some tests, I find that the each execution stops at

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
```

with the error "Couldn't find Category without an ID". Params doesn't have an :id hash when I printed it out. Is this because I have to save it into the database before the default :id field is created?

Comment: Please add your view code with the link. It is likely that you are not including the "id" in the link.

Comment: Did you try with this code "format.html { new_or_edit, :id => params[:id] }" and Category.find(:id)?

Comment: You're trying to handle new, edit, and update all within the same action. Routing for the new action doesn't include an id parameter because by convention you're instantiating an object. Edit and update actions will use an id parameter because you're editing/updating an existing record. You really need to set up separate new, edit, and update actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is trying to unify two inherently different actions: new and edit.

params is a hash of parameters you get from the client.

When you create a new object, `params[:id]` is left blank since the id attribute of a newly created object is the responsibility of the server, not the client.

When you edit an existing object, `params[:id]` is not blank since the object already exists in the database and has an id. The meaning of `params[:id]` here is "Please edit object with id param[:id] using these attributes".

After explaining this, when you create a **new** object this line:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:id])
```

Fails since `params[:id]` is empty.